# Gamepad on VisualBoyAdvance not working

Tags: kubuntu, games, emulation

I installed visualboyadvance/visualboyadvance-gtk (gvba) on my kubuntu (utopic) and tried to assign the buttons and DPad to the Jostick1, but it doesn't work. The gamepad itself is working fine (KDE recognizes it and it works great in mupen64plus).

How can I get it to work? Is this a bug? Are there workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using **antimicro**. This package maps joystick buttons to keyboard keys which I then use to control visualboy.